# How to make RDP authentication using Java?

Tags: java, rdp

I have login and password for RDP. I can connect to remote desktop using standard program in Windows. However, what I need is not to connect and see desktop but check whether the login and password pair is valid or not. And I need to realize it using Java. I have idea to use socket and RDP protocol but it is very low level for me. I need some ready realization over these (library). I hope I explicitly explain my problem.

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/jrdesktop/
https://github.com/marc-ashman/jrdp

Comment: Thanks. Have you ever used these libraries?